# Why Eureka TableView‘s Section header string always display uppercase character？？？

Tags: ios, eureka-forms

My code is very simple :

```
class ViewController:FormViewController{ 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //set section header and footer
        let section0 = Section(header: "Header 0", footer: "Footer 0")

        section0 <<< LabelRow(){row in
            row.title = "row 1"
        }

        form +++ section0
    }
}
```

When I run App ,The demo picture is below :

[image]

You can see the header's title changed to "HEADER 0",but the footer's no changed!!!

I try use normal UITableViewViewController with add delegate methods to do it:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Header 0"
    }
```

In this case is all right!!! the header's title is exactly the same as "Header 0"

Why when I use Eureka TableView ,It's header title string is all Turn into a capitalized form？？？Can anyone tell me??? Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: This is not Eureka that does this but standard Apple `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912980/uitableview-titleforheaderinsection-shows-all-caps